# Add class active when clicking the menu link with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML

```
<div id="top" class="shadow">
  <ul class="gprc"> 
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link1/">Text1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link2/">Text2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link3/">Text3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link4">Text4</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

and JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
    $('#top a').each(function () {
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });    
});
```

The problem is that when i click on the Home link all tabs are getting active class and don't understand why. I need it for the first link to not get any active class.

Comment: Why using `each()` loop? this can be easily achieved on `click()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also looking for this solution and I have tested your code. On the first approach all links are highlighted and when I click other links it is working properly. The problem was on the home page because all links are highlighted because there is "no event been received" when the page is loaded, the code will work if you send a command or by clicking each links, theoretically. To stop this behavior, I found this code to one of the answers above, add this code and change the ".sibling()" to ".previousSibling()"

```
$(this).parent().sibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
```

".sibling()" will highlighted at the end of your links change it to ".previousSibling()" so it will go to first (Li)

```
$(this).parent().previoussibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
```

Your code will be like this:

```
    $(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
    $('#top a').each(function () {
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().previoussibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Reading this answer I'm assuming that English isn't your first language? Could you, please, re-read this answer and break it up into paragraphs and sentences, in order to make it more understandable. Incidentally "bcoz" should be "because." As for your salutation, "*Thanks and God Bless*" - please remove that, it's irrelevant to your answer (as are "hello," signatures, and many other things). While I respect your intent, it's out of place here. I was going to edit myself, to try and improve, but I struggled to work out what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

Check this , this will only activates clicked tab , remove active for all and then add for the one clicked

```
$("#top a").click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/rLddf/1/)

Comment: Don't know why it's doing nothing.

Comment: I added on href="1" http://jsfiddle.net/rLddf/9/. If you click it you will see that on page load tab won't remain active.

Comment: When i click on home, after the page loads this single tab should be inactive (removeClass('active');). When i click on the rest of the links, let's say second link for example, link should get active and remain active after page load or refresh.

Comment: http://www.checkprg.com This is my site, when i click now, the links are not working anymore. Have a look.

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle yet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40131/discussion-between-bharath-rallapalli-and-adrian)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this out. It will help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#sidebar li a').each(function () {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            if (path.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                var current = path.indexOf('?');
            }
            else {
                var current = path;
            }
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var currenturl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            if (currenturl.toLowerCase() == current.toLowerCase()) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var par = $(this).parent();
                par.addClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a `foreach` loop on all `<a>` tags within your `#top` div. So of course it'll add the class `active` to all of them.

I think what you're trying to do is this: http://jsfiddle.net/rLddf/4/

I used the `click` event instead.

**edit** switched link to Kristof Feys example - more efficient.

Comment: I need it to get active only the tab that i clicked, not after i click each link to get colored.

Comment: @ScottRowell doesn't work for me, i have tried with jquer 1.9.1, 1.10.1, 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(function() { 
    $('#yourMenu a').each(function(){
        $current = location.href;
        $target= $(this).attr('href');
            if ( $target== $current) 
            {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I found it easier to just add an additional if statement so that the function would fire on all pages except the home page which met my needs.

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname, 
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");         
        $('#top a').each(function(){
          if ( window.location.pathname != '/' ){
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
                  $(this).addClass('active');
              } 
            }             
        });
 });
```

You could also add in an else statement to show an active link on the homepage by targeting the link directly if required.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#top a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/creuh/1/)

Comment: this works, but doesn't go through the link. I mean when i click it, it only remains selected the link i click but doesn't access the link.

Comment: to go through the link, just remove the line "e.preventDefault();"

Comment: @KristofFeys now goes through the link but it doesn't remain selected after.