# How to make one submenu active in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Here I want to make one submenu active out of four submenu. This is for dynamic slug .

```
<div class="solution_tabs">
   @foreach($allMenu as $menu)
   <ul class="submenu">
      @if(isset($menu->submenus))
      @foreach($menu->submenus as $submenu)
      @if(isset($submenu->page->slug))
      <li class="active"><a href="{{url($submenu->page->slug)}}">{{ $submenu->name}}</a></li>
      @else
      <li><a href="{{url($submenu->page->slug)}}">{{ $submenu->name}}</a></li>
      @endif
      @endforeach
      @endif
   </ul>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

[same as this image,i want one active submenu from dynamic submeun of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyfkK.png)

Comment: Try this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639287/add-class-active-when-clicking-the-menu-link-with-jquery

Comment: I just confused what to compare for that with submenu . This didn't help me ! I need if else in laravel blade

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the current URL with your link URLs in order to detect coincidences. One way to accomplish it could be injecting request in your blade file, using

```
@inject('request', 'Illuminate\Http\Request')
```

and then check for matches like this:

```
<li class="{{ $request->segment(1) == $submenu->page->slug ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{url($submenu->page->slug)}}">{{ $submenu->name}}</a></li>
```

Please note that `segment()` is 0 based, so `segment(1)` works when your url is like `example.com/segment(0)/page->slug`